# Time validation in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am new in Laravel and using 5.5 ver. I have two input field **star_time** and **end_time**

```
Start time Input Value is : 10:00AM

End Time Input value is: 01:00PM
```

this is my validation rule

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'start_time'  => 'required|date_format:H:iA',
    'end_time'=>'required|date_format:H:iA|after:start_time',
]);
```

every time given "**The end time does not match the format H:iA**"

Please help how to validate start time and end time and end time bigger than start time and time format with am/pm

Answer (score 2):

This is late answer to you question but here is solution for it. just write **H** as **h** in you validator.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'start_time'  => 'required|date_format:h:iA',
    'end_time'=>'required|date_format:h:iA|after:start_time',
]);
```

You should use **h** instead of **H** as you are using A for **AM and PM**.

- **H** work for 24 hours
- **h** work for 12 hours
- **A** (use upercase) work for AM or PM